# Cron job * is replaced by file name in current directory

Tags: ubuntu, shell-script, cron

This is my first shell script program, so i think this is more likely a silly question for you all.

**Overview of problem**
My need is to write a shell command for installing our Node.js server.

- Server needs to install 3 crons as dependency. We offer 3 different
  environment.

**Problem**
So when i try to assign cron(string) to variable then all the star in the string are replaced by filenames in the current working directory.

```
VAR1="*/1       *       *       *       *      /usr/bin/wget -O /var/tmp/output-folder-path  https://my.server.com:12000/cron/push >> /dev/null 2>&1"
```

Now, when i do `echo $VAR1` then output  is like following

```
*/3 file1.txt file2.txt generated.txt sample.sh file1.txt file2.txt generated.txt sample.sh file1.txt file2.txt generated.txt sample.sh file1.txt file2.txt generated.txt sample.sh /usr/bin/wget -O /var/tmp/output-folder-here https://my.server.com:12000/cron/push >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Output of `ls` command in that directory is

```
file1.txt  file2.txt  generated.txt  sample.sh
```

Comment: I have a very hard time imagining exactly what you are trying to do here, but you can at least certainly prevent those asterisks from being interpreted as glob patterns by using `"$VAR1"` instead of `$VAR1`.

Comment: @Celada This helped me. Thanks, you can post this as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a backspace in front of the * so it's not used as a wildcard.

```
VAR1="\*/1       \*       \*       \*       \*      /usr/bin/wget -O /var/tmp/output-folder-path  https://my.server.com:12000/cron/push >> /dev/null 2>&1"
```

**EDIT**

I was wrong. The * doesn't escape when you do it like I posted above. Instead use single quotes.

```
VAR1='*/1       *       *       *       *      /usr/bin/wget -O /var/tmp/output-folder-path  https://my.server.com:12000/cron/push >> /dev/null 2>&1'
```

Additionally, if you don't want to use single quotes you can quote the variable when you print it.

```
echo "$VAR1"
```

On a side note I don't think I would ever embed a cron command in a shell script. I doesn't seem like it would be a good practice and it won't work unless you plan to update crontab with the script.

Comment: I have already attempted this, escaping character (\) is also getting printed.

Comment: It shouldn't but as long as you're not using variables you can change it to single quotes instead and leave out the backspaces.